# Firebase analytics are not appearing in the dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated Firebase Analytics by following their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/)
And I have also downloaded their [sample app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging), in both the cases I am getting these message in the logs and in both the cases I am not getting the analytics data.

In log I am getting this message is this ok?

```
com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics V/FA: Session started, time: 918306437
com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics D/FA: Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto}]
com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics V/FA: Using measurement service
com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics V/FA: Connecting to remote service
com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics D/FA: Connected to remote service
com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
```

Answer (score 0):

The logcat looks healthy. "D/FA: Logging event" line show you that you have successfully logged the event. Please make sure the app is using the correct project id. The id is set in mobilesdk_app_id value in google-services.json file. You might be sending data to another project.
One of the first lines that Firebase Analytics logs is the app package and firebase project it. Make sure it matches your Firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs suggest that even though call to

> Logging Event  (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto}]

is successful, yet the Event is not scheduled to be uploaded to the Firebase Console.

Do you have any components which are running in some other process in your app? Because if you are trying to log a event from a non-main process component, it will not get scheduled to be uploaded to Firebase. The reason for this is that the non-main process will have its *Application* object instantiated but no *ContentProviders* (as they are instantiated only in the main process). Therefore Firebase initialisation can only happen in the main process.

Another reason could be if your *client-id* inside *google-services.json* file does not match with the client-id specified on Firebase. Please provide some more information if this doesn't solve your problem.

Hope this helps.