# Firebase analytics Logging event returns error

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I have integrated Firebase Analytics in my app and enabled logcat. When sending log event, I got these message:

```
09-16 12:29:52.254 7233-7264 D/FA: Logging event (FE): add_payment_info, Bundle[{achievement_id=112, _o=app}]
09-16 12:29:52.255 7233-7264 V/FA: Using measurement service
09-16 12:29:52.255 7233-7264 V/FA: Connecting to remote service
09-16 12:29:52.259 7233-7264 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 44850636
09-16 12:29:52.282 7233-7264 D/FA: Connected to remote service
09-16 12:29:52.282 7233-7264 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
09-16 12:29:53.259 7233-7264 D/FA: Application backgrounded. Logging engagement
09-16 12:29:53.263 7233-7264 D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=1853}]
09-16 12:29:58.271 7233-7264 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
```

According to this question: [Firbase analytics are not apearing in the dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481070/firbase-analytics-are-not-apearing-in-the-dashboard), I think this line "`Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=1853}]`" means the event is not logged successfully. How to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Did it got resolved?

Comment: @maňish yeah, turns out it's not a failing status. The log info showed up after a few hours.

Comment: thanks for the comment and saving my time in more R&D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question: this is not an error log. A few hours after deploying, the log info showed up.